# A more pythonic way of adding sampled rows to a dataframe and calculating the mean

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to CV 10 random samples from a dataframe and take the mean, this is my incredibly basic version, it feels very clunky.  Can anyone recommend a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
graph_data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(10):
    y = source_data.loc[filter_1,'attribute'].sample(n=100000)
    y.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    graph_data[x] = y

graph_data['mean'] = graph_data.mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
N = 100000
L=[source_data.loc[filter_1,'attribute'].sample(n=N).reset_index(drop=True) for x in range(10)]
graph_data = pd.concat(L, axis=1).mean(axis=1).to_frame('mean')
```